# How to define expression for dynamic drop down list

Tags: silktest

How do I define an expression (or any other alternative method) when I want to select a value from a dynamic drop down list?

ex:
drop down list has these values:

```
Plan A (X)
Plan B (Y)
Plan C (Z)
```

where, X, Y and Z are all random numbers.

Is there a way where I can define my selection to select the text up to "Plan #" and ignore the "(X)"?

Comment: What do you mean ignore the X? do you mean if X equals this or that number the take it out of the drop down?

Comment: Well, when I want to select a value from the drop list, i have to enter the exact wording (ex: "Plan A (10)").

Comment: Since the value "10" changes time to time, is there a way to define it so that i will choose "Plan A (X)" regardless of the number in the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using wildcards, those are usually supported by SilkTest. 
For your example this would be

```
"Plan A*"
```